# Default parameter values not working

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

In a report I'm working on, there is a parameter which uses a query to return its values.
Both the 'value' and 'label' are strings.

I ticked the 'allow multi' box.

I have added some hard-coded values to the 'default value' section.

These values do match some of the ones returned as the 'value' part of the query.

However, when previewed, the drop-down list has no entries ticked.

I have searched for this problem, but all results seem to refer to deployment issues - this isn't the case here; I'm running it in VS on my PC.

Any ideas, please, good people?

Comment: You can't set a default value which doesn't exist in the available values, what is the need for do that? I'd analyze again the requeriment.

Comment: That's why I stated that they DO exist in the query results....

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. Double check if you are harcoding exactly the same values as strings. Also try recreating the parameter.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your parameter set up to your answer.  I would imagine this is a very simple fix that will be obvious as soon as we can actually see what you currently have in place.

Comment: What you're describing should work. Just some suggestions: it is case sensitive so check that the case matches, make sure there aren't trailing spaces in the values, are you using SQL or MDX for the query?

Comment: The case is correct - the hard-coded values were copy/pasted from a query in SSMS.
One thing I didn't mention is that the value field in the table is of type 'uniqueidentifier' - which manifests itself as a string usually; could this being causing the non-matching with a string in the default value list?

Answer (score 0):

After posting my last comment, I modified the hard-coded values to use =Guid.Parse("")...

It now works.
Obviously a 'uniqueidentifier' *looks* like a string, but isn't....